# Gradle can't resolve dependencies through my http proxy

Tags: gradle

when I try to run `gradle dependencies` on my computer I am getting a 407 status code "Proxy Authentication Required."

I created a gradle.properties file in my `%GRADLE_HOME%` directory.  `gradle.properties` contains the following entries:

```
systemProp.proxySet='true'
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=%myUserNameHere%
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=%myPasswordHere%
```

I can successfully get through my proxy for ruby gems by setting HTTP_PROXY to the following value:
http://%myUserNameHere%:%myPasswordHere%@http-proxy.nwie.net:8080

I am using gradle-1.3, please let me know if there is something I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I tried setting systemProp.http.proxyUser to a new value in domain/username format.  Below are my current properties file contents:

```
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=http-proxy.nwie.net/%USERNAME%
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=%PASSWORD%
```

I am currently getting the same error message I found initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some dependencies are fetched from servers that run over HTTPS so you need to specify values for https properties as well:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=http-proxy.nwie.net/%USERNAME%
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=%PASSWORD%
```

Comment: When working with CNTLM on an OSX machine, we needed to use `systemProp.https.proxyHost` as well as `systemProp.http.proxyHost`, and the respective proxyPort configs. We could leave out the proxyUser and proxyPassword settings, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an NTLM proxy (Usually found in a windows environment with active directory). If so, You may have to specify the domain name with the username in the format domain/username.
Take a look at this link.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Thanks uttamkini, I tried your suggestions but I got the same error.  I have updated my post with my new properties file contents