# what are the generic URLs need to be enable to add dependencies in Android project using proxy?

Tags: android, networking, dependencies, build.gradle, dependency-management

In my organization due security they restricted network like social media sites, other sites. Because of this, I am unable to add some Android dependencies in my project `build.gradle`.

**Eg:-**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

But I am able to add default android dependencies like below.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

So, here my question is what are the generic URLs need to be enable to get all dependencies `build.gradle`. I will ask them to enable those URLs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe URls are dependency specific, will very from one to other.
Why don't you configure your gradle for proxy?

[Complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828787/gradle-cant-resolve-dependencies-through-my-http-proxy?rq=1)